# Remove scrollbar blue shadow with android:minSdkVersion="8" at the bottom and top

Tags: android, scrollbar

Remove scrollbar blue shadow with  android:minSdkVersion="8" at the bottom and top

I am trying to show a scrollbar in my activity however the scrollbar shows a blue shadow when it reaches the end either on top or at bottom

I have tried

in java

```
lv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
        lv.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
```

and 
in xml

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
```

these didnot work

and

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

doesnot work because of minsdk 8

what should I do so that blue shadows disappear

Comment: Try this.

android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"

Comment: android:overScrollMode="never"
doesnot work because of minsdk 8

Comment: I am also using minsdk 8 and its working fine. Clean your project and re-try it.

Comment: eclipse actually shows the warning of minsdk cleaned the project and it worked thanks